# Using the Stefan-Boltzmann equation to calculate the heat dissipated by a cable

Tags: thermodynamics

This seems like more of a physics than electronics question, so I've decided to ask it here.

---

I am currently studying *The Art of Electronics*, third edition, by Horowitz and Hill. Exercise 1.6 says the following:

> **C. Power in resistors**
> The power dissipated by a resistor (or any other device) is $P = IV$. Using Ohm’s law, you can get the equivalent forms $P = I^2 R$ and $P = V^2 / R$.
> **Exercise 1.6.** Optional exercise: New York City requires about $10^{10}$ watts of electrical power, at 115 volts (this is plausible:  10 million people averaging 1 kilowatt each). A heavy power cable might be an inch in diameter. Let’s calculate what will happen  if we try to supply the power through a cable 1 foot in diameter  made of pure copper. Its resistance is $0.05 \ \mu \Omega$ ($5 \times 10^{−8}$ ohms) per foot. Calculate (a) the power lost per foot from “$I^2R$ losses," (b) the length of cable over which you will lose all $10^{10}$ watts, and (c) how hot the cable will get, if you know the physics involved ($ \omega = 6 \times 10^{-12} \text{W}/\text{K}^4 \text{cm}^2$). If you have done your computations correctly, the result should seem preposterous. What is the solution to this puzzle.

I managed to get the answer to (a) as $3.8 \times 10^8 \ \text{W}/\text{ft}$, and then $\dfrac{10^{10} \text{W}}{3.8 \times 10^8 \ \text{W}/\text{ft}} = 26.32 \ \text{ft}$ for (b).

I'm now trying to solve (c). I'm referring to [this](https://github.com/milesdai/TAoE3Solutions/blob/master/Chapter1.pdf) (unofficial) solutions document, which claims that, to calculate the heat dissipated by the cable, we can use the [Stefan-Boltzmann equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stefan%E2%80%93Boltzmann_law):

[image]

However, according to the Wikipedia article, the Stefan-Boltzmann equation is $P = A \varepsilon\sigma T^{4} \Rightarrow T = \sqrt[4]{\dfrac{P}{A \epsilon \sigma}}$, where $\epsilon$ is the emissivity of the body and $\sigma \approx 5.670374419184429453\dots \times 10^{-8}\,\mathrm {W\,m^{-2}\,K^{-4}}$. Compared to the (again, unofficial) solutions manual, the Stefan-Boltzmann equation is different (the Wikipedia one includes the emissivity $\epsilon$), and compared to the textbook problem statement, the value for $\sigma$ is different (the textbook lists it as $ \omega = 6 \times 10^{-12} \text{W}/\text{K}^4 \text{cm}^2$). For the value of $\sigma$, as mentioned in the beginning section of the Wikipedia article, the [Stefan-Boltzmann constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stefan%E2%80%93Boltzmann_constant) was redefined in 2019, but I don't think this accounts for the discrepancy here. So are both of these errors (in the textbook and unofficial solutions)? Or am I missing something?

Comment: Most likely the textbook wants you to find an approximation only. 5.67 is close enough to 6, and emissivity of (oxidised) copper ~1. The solution manual is a bit inconsistent though, since it keeps the precision on the area and final result.

Comment: @hiccups Eh, I checked this, but I'm not sure that it's accurate to say that the emissivity of oxidised copper is ~1: https://www.flukeprocessinstruments.com/en-us/service-and-support/knowledge-center/infrared-technology/emissivity-metals

Comment: @hiccups After reading Chemomechanics's answer, I'm guessing that the authors of the unofficial solutions are just taking the emissivity to be ~1 for the sake of simplicity, so you're probably right in this case.

Comment: Note that the emissivity approximation is conservative; other selections would yield even higher temperatures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not an error; the authors are telling you in the problem statement to approximate 5.67 as 6 for that constant. (Similarly, $g$ is often taken as 10 m/s² and $\pi$ as 3 for such back-of-the-envelope calculations.) Then, the solution is completed without rounding until the final estimate of (temperature)/(Sun surface temperature) > 2, which leads to the resolution.

Comment: Hmm, ok. And with the conversion $1 \ \text{m}^2 = 10000 \ \text{cm}^2$, then I guess this makes sense. Furthermore, the authors of the unofficial solutions manual seem to have simplified the emissivity of copper to be ~1, even though this doesn't really seem to be accurate. So there's a lot of confusing simplifying going on here.

Comment: Since the book has essentially nothing to do with heat transfer, the exercise is really just for those who are already well familiar with the topic and its idealizations/approximations and would like to gain extra insight into a typical electrical engineering scenario. This is even indicated in the problem statement.